# Can I use the function "get" with an assoc list?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have the following code:

```
(setq months '((january 1) (february 2) ...))
```

Can I use `get` to use this list as a map (with keys and values)

Like:

```
(get 'months 'january)
```

and get the result: 1

Is it possible to do this in Lisp without explicitly setting the properties like this:

```
(setf (get 'months 'january) 1)
(setf (get 'months 'february) 2)
...
```

If this is not possible in Common Lisp, is it possible in any other dialect of Lisp?

Comment: Why not use `ASSOC` to access elements from an assoc list? Why use `GET`? What advantage would that have? GET is for symbol property lists, not for assoc lists.

Comment: @RainerJoswig I'm a beginner in LISP. I didn't know ASSOC. This is the answer I was looking for. Thanks! If you put your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Nothing wrong with being a beginner.  Asking Emacs first is very helpful, in two ways: (1) getting your answer quickly, (2) getting to know Emacs. They are related in that when Emacs answers you it uses its own terms, helping you ask even it (or here) even better next time.  To ask Emacs for information about `assoc`: `M-x apropos RET assoc RET`.  Or try `M-x apropos RET association list RET`. (Try `C-h c apropos TAB` to see a list of other apropos commands.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. The [documentation for `get`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_get.htm) says that the usage is

> get symbol indicator &optional default => value
>
> get finds a property on the property list of symbol whose property
>   indicator is identical to indicator, and returns its corresponding
>   property value. If there are multiple properties[1](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_get.htm) with that property
>   indicator, get uses the first such property. If there is no property
>   with that property indicator, default is returned.

A [property list](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_p.htm#property_list) is defined as:

> property list n. 1. a list containing an even number of elements that
>   are alternating names (sometimes called indicators or keys) and values
>   (sometimes called properties). When there is more than one name and
>   value pair with the identical name in a property list, the first such
>   pair determines the property. 2. (of a symbol) the component of the
>   symbol containing a property list.

Your data is in the form of an [association list](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_a.htm#association_list):

> association list n. a list of conses representing an association of
>   keys with values, where the car of each cons is the key and the cdr is
>   the value associated with that key.

As such, you'd access values in it with [`assoc`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_assocc.htm).  You *could* work with a property list, in which case you'd either use [`getf`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_getf.htm) if it's not a symbol's property list, and `get` (as described above) if it is a symbol's property list.  Here are examples of all three approaches.

### Association List

```
CL-USER> (defparameter *months-alist*
           '((january . 1)
             (february . 2)
             (march . 3)))


*MONTHS-ALIST*
CL-USER> (cdr (assoc 'february *months-alist*))
2
```

### Property List

```
CL-USER> (defparameter *months-plist*
           '(january 1 february 2 march 3))
*MONTHS-PLIST*
CL-USER> (getf *months-plist* 'march)
3
```

### Property List of a Symbol (uncommon)

```
CL-USER> (setf (get '*months* 'january) 1
               (get '*months* 'february) 2
               (get '*months* 'march) 3)
3
CL-USER> (get '*months* 'january)
1
```

### Other Ways

Of course, you could also use a hash map, or in the case of this data where things are ordered, you could find the position of an element:

#### Hash Tables

```
CL-USER> (defparameter *months-hash* (make-hash-table :test 'eq))
*MONTHS-HASH*
CL-USER> (setf (gethash 'january *months-hash*) 1
               (gethash 'february *months-hash*) 2
               (gethash 'march *months-hash*) 3)
3
CL-USER> (gethash 'february *months-hash*)
2 ; the value
T ; it was present in the table
```

#### Position

```lisp
CL-USER> (defparameter *months-sequence* 
           #(january february march april may june july august september))
*MONTHS-SEQUENCE*
CL-USER> (1+ (position 'april *months-sequence*))
4
```

Answer (score -1):

You are using [a-list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_list) as a data structure to implement associative maps. It has *O(n)* complexity (linear), so is not a good structure for large maps.

Common Lisp has a rich library with containers see its [hyperspec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Front/Contents.htm), notably [hash-tables](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/18_a.htm). They might be much more relevant. You could still use a-lists if you believe they are very short (e.g. with the [ASSOC](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_assocc.htm) Common Lisp function). You could also consider [B-trees](http://www.cliki.net/cl-btree)...

Comment: my question was: is there any way i can use GET, as in (GET 'months 'january), to get the result that i want from the list?